# Rendering a component using a variable in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

I have a list of `react-icons` passed through props in a "Card Component". In my Card component's render method, I have something like this:

```js
render() {
  ...
  {
     this.props.icons.map(icon => {
        return (
          <div className="icon-square">
            /*   What should I do here so I render the "icon" variable"   */
          </div>
        )
     })
   }
}
```

Note: The list consists of react-icons which are React components themselves.

I tried a lot of things, but I can't quite figure out how I can render the icon. It would be awesome if someone could help me. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `{icon}`?

Comment: Please include what `props.icons` array is so we can see what each element is that you are attempting to render. Include what you've already tried so we're not playing 20 questions. [Minimal, Complete, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Have you tried `icon()`?

Comment: I'll go with @NadiaChibrikova's answer. Of course if the `icon` is JSX element.

Comment: Ah yes, icon(icon) works. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let say you've passed a list of an icon like

```
import { FaBeer, FaBug, FaAnchor, FaCoffee } from 'react-icons/fa';

const icons = [FaBeer, FaBug, FaAnchor, FaCoffee];

ReactDOM.render(
    <CardComponent icons = {icons} />,
    document.querySelector('root')
};
```

**CardComponent.js**

```
class CardComponent extends React.Component{
...

render() {

  // Icon is a Component
  return (
    this.props.icons.map((Icon) => {
     return <Icon />
    });
  )

 }
}
```

Comment: This answer is very similar to @lissettdm's answer

Comment: @Kurosaki_Ishigo My answer specifically indicates what and how props we should pass to CardComponent.As Jam is a new contributor, So I thought it would be more helpful if I could explain him as deep as possible. Sometimes new programmer like me faces difficulties to understand even the answers from the SOF community.

Answer (score 3):

If the icon is a react component, then:

```
this.props.icons.map(Icon => {
        return (
          <div className="icon-square">
            <Icon/>
          </div>
        )
     })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is two difference for use your icon, If you pass as a JSX you should use `{icon}`
But if you pass as a component you should use like this `<Icon/>`

Comment: Yes, brother, You're absolutely right. I agree with you. It was my mistake. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think wrapping you need to just put icon is `{}`

```
render() {
  ...
  {
     this.props.icons.map(icon => {
        return (
          <div className="icon-square">
            {icon}
          </div>
        )
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried `{icon}` and it does not work. I checked it Google Chrome's Inspect and this is what I get, `<div class="icon-square></div>` There is nothing inside the `icon-square` div